# Надо ли создавать прокладку для обработки данных после получения выборки?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Смотрю в [документации](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html) описание метода **query** класса **Session(_SessionClassMethods)**:

> Class-level methods for :class:`.Session`, :class:`.sessionmaker`

Я верно понимаю, что если через менеджер контекста создаю экземпляр класса:

```
from clickhouse_sqlalchemy import make_session
Base_ch= get_declarative_base(metadata=metadata_ch)


class MyTable(Base_ch):
    ....

with make_session(create_engine(...)) as conn:
    all_rows_MyTable = conn.query(MyTable).filter(..).all()
```

то итерировать и обращаться к его свойства могу только пока существует сессия? Т.е. если я решу его передать во внешнюю функцию и в конце кода вызвать (после аналогичных запросов к другим таблицам), то могу словить ошибку, если сессия работы с этой таблицей в БД уже истекла?

Получается чтобы мне такое мутить, то надо создавать отдельный класс, который бы записывал в себе нужные параметры из выборки?